# Issue with wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

What may be reason when i am using multiple plugins then some plugin showing in widget sidebar
but some or not like
plugin "wp-auctions" is showing in widget sidebar but
plugin "ultimate-auction" is not showing.

I am using "twentythirteen" theme.

please help me.

Comment: add ultimate-auction to sidebar ?

Comment: it's showing in sidebar of dashboard page but not in available widgets area.
widget area page url like
wordpress/wp-admin/widgets.php

Comment: check for js errors in console area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, take a look at this, http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-auction/installation/

It seemed ultimate-auction is used on a page, not as a widget

Try create a new Page:

> Enter this text "[wdm_auction_listing]" as a shortcode inside this new
>   page and publish it.

Then visit this page to see the auction list.

<strike>Goto the Admin page, choose **Appearance->Widgets**, check **Available Widgets** on the left side, ultimate-auction might be there, and you need **drag** it to the Main Widget Area on the right side.</strike>

Comment: but "ultimate -auction" is not available in widget area while if i activate another plugin then it available in widget area. why?

Comment: ya i got solution becoz ultimate-auction is used on a page, not as a widget.
Thanks for reply.